# Use value returned by one function in another function

Tags: backbone.js, sugarcrm

I am new to backbone and sugarcrm. Can anyone please explain how to use the value returned by one function in another function?

This is the pseudo code :

```
({
extendsFrom: 'RecordView',

initialize: function(options) {
    this._super('initialize', [options]);
    this.context.on('button:get_tax:click', this.get_tax, this);
    this.model.addValidationTask('addressValidation',_.bind(this.save_button, this));


},


save_button: function(fields, errors, callback) {

use the value of 'currentTax' variable 
},

get_tax: function() {

    var currentTax = this.model.get('taxrate_name');
    return currentTax;

}
})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
save_button: function(fields, errors, callback) {
    var curTax = this.get_tax();
},
```

Explanation:

`get_tax` is a function that you have defined within the `({`...`})` object.
Backbone calls the `initialize` function with that object being accessible via `this`.

By using `_.bind(this.save_button, this`) (in initialize) you are binding the `this` object to the `save_button` function, meaning that it will also be available as `this` within your function when called.

Therefore you can access the same object with `this` in that function and just call the object's function and retrieve the value.